# Supabase Error "404: User not found" for custom JWT

Tags: authentication, jwt, supabase

In my project, I am using **Supabase** and **Express**. What I am trying to do is I create and sign jwt in express and pass it to Supabase, but when I do this i see following error log:

```
{"component":"api","error":"404: User not found","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"404: User not found","path":"/user",...
```

I think I cannot set `Authorization` correctly. My code to set auth

```
      const jwtResponse = await fetch(
        `https://jwt_fetch_url}`
      );

      const { jwtToken, user } = await jwtResponse.json();

      secretSupabase.functions.setAuth(jwtToken);
      secretSupabase.realtime.setAuth(jwtToken);
      (secretSupabase as any).rest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${jwtToken}`;
```

I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the steps you took to obtain the error message?